$\frac{\partial \ ^2 u}{\partial x^2}$+$\frac{\partial \ ^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}$+ $\frac{\partial \ ^2 u}{\partial y^2}$=0
I am new to PDE and this question can be solved by separation of variables.
$\text Attempt$: Assume $u(x,y)= X(x)Y(y) $, then I get $\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+\frac{X'(x)Y'(y)}{X(x)Y(y)}+\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=0$. I don't know how to get the next step, any hints? Thanks in advance.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

if you want to use this method, I would suggest to first change the variables, keep $x$ but replace $y$ by $y + ax$ for a suitable $a$ to get rid of the mixed term

What are the boundary conditions?

@Gonçalo no boundary condition, just to solve this equation.

The PDE
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0 \tag{1}
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+a\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)u
=0, \tag{2}
$$
provided
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b=1 \\
ab=1
\end{cases} 
\implies
\begin{cases}
a=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
b=\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\bar{a}.
\end{cases} \tag{3}
$$
The general solution to $(2)$ is
$$
u(x,y)=f(x-ay)+g(x-\bar{a}y), \tag{4}
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary holomorphic$^{(*)}$ functions.

$^{(*)}$ Edited cf. user8268's comment.

$a$ is a complex number, so $f$ and $g$ should be holomorphic (rather than twice differentiable)
