Stuck on solving basic elliptic PDEs
image
The problem is to solve the elliptic PDE
$$u_{xx} + 4 u_{yy} = 0$$
The solution is said to be
$$u = f_1 (y + 2 i x) + f_2 (y - 2 i x)$$
I derived the characteristic equation for the PDE:
$$\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 + 4 = 0$$
and transformed the variables
$$\begin{cases}
v = y - 2 i x \\
w = y + 2 i x
\end{cases}$$
but I only got Laplace's equation
$$u_{vv} + u_{ww} = 0$$
instead of
$$u = f_1 (y + 2 i x) + f_2 (y - 2 i x)$$
What should I do?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4915094/frac-partial-2-u-partial-x2-frac-partial-2-u-partial-x-parti/4916047#4916047

You shouldn't have got Laplaces equation in $u, v$. Letting $u(x, y) \to u(v(x, y), w(x,y)) = u(y - 2ix, y + 2ix)$ and computing derivatives gives
\begin{align}
u_{x} &\to u_{v} v_{x} + u_{w} w_{x} \
&= 2i(- u_{v} + u_{w}) \
u_{xx} &\to 2i (- u_{vv} v_{x} - u_{vw} w_{x} + u_{wv} v_{x} + u_{ww} w_{x}) \
&= -4 (u_{vv} - 2 u_{vw} + u_{ww}) \
u_{y} &\to u_{v} v_{y} + u_{w} w_{y} \
&= u_{v} + u_{w} \
u_{yy} &\to u_{vv} v_{y} + u_{vw} w_{y} + u_{wv} v_{y} + u_{ww} w_{y} \
&= u_{vv} + 2 u_{vw} + u_{ww}
\end{align}
and hence $$u_{xx} + 4 u_{yy} = 0 \to 8 u_{vw} = 0$$

@MatthewCassell
Thank you for clarifying. I calculated one more time and mine was wrong.
However, the normal form 8u_vw differs from what I have learned as the "normal form of elliptic PDE", which is u_vv + u_ww + (lower terms) = 0 so I am quite confused.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation#:~:text=%2C-,into%20the%20canonical%20form,as%20desired.,-In%20higher%20dimensions)
Do you know why the answer is different? Is there any exception for the normal form? Thank you.

Do you want to solve the PDE or to rewrite it in its normal form?

@Gonçalo The normal form. More specifically, the reason I got stuck is the inconsistency of the normal form of elliptic PDEs. For this specific problem the normal form was 8u_vw but my textbook and Wikipedia say the normal form is always in (u_vv + u_ww + (else)) form.

The normal form of your PDE is the Laplace equation, and its general solution is the one given in your second equation. These facts are not incompatible.
